# Spouse of US citizen: can I visit my husband in the US and then stay and adjust status?

Tags: usa, visa, immigration, marriage

I have been married to my husband for 4 years. I live in the UK and he is living in the US with our 2 year old daughter.

Can I visit the US on a ESTA and then stay and do a adjustment of status? I have heard of people doing this after getting married and just staying, but I want to know if I can do this now so I don't have to apply outside of the US and be away from my family for even longer.

Comment: Not a good idea.  This is specifically prohibited.

Comment: @LorenPechtel it's not that simple.  Immediate relatives of US citizens are allowed to adjust status from VWP to permanent residence, but if you intend to do that when you enter the US then you are not admissible as a temporary visitor.

Comment: @phoog You can adjust status when here but entering on a tourist visa with the intent to change status is not permitted.  It's a trick they are wise to.

Comment: @LorenPechtel yes, I'm aware of that: "if you intend to do that when you enter the US then you are not admissible as a temporary visitor" is exactly why "entering on a tourist visa with the intent to change status is not permitted."  My point is that saying "this is specifically prohibited" doesn't make clear precisely what is wrong with the plan.

Comment: Forgive the personal question, but why are you not living with your husband and daughter? It's a question you will be asked.

Comment: @DJClayworth one might also wonder why mrsTee didn't apply earlier for an immigrant visa.